# Is it really possible to find Group A Pokemon on a (!!) bush with the Pokewalker?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokewalker), when you uncover a (!!) bush on the Pokewalker, you can find either a Group B Pokemon or a Group A Pokemon for that route, while a (!!!) bush always gives you a Group A Pokemon.

For example, on [Yellow Forest](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yellow_Forest_%28Pok%C3%A9walker_Route%29) a Group B Pokemon are Pikachu with Flail and Pikachu with Volt Tackle, while the Group A Pokemon are Pikachu with Surf and Pikachu with Fly.

However, I've caught about six Pikachu now from (!!) bushes and they're all Group B (Pikachu with Volt Tackle). I haven't seen a single (!!!) bush, either.

**Can a (!!) bush really produce a Group A Pokemon**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (!!) Bushes will produce Group A Pokemon, but at around half the chance that they will appear in (!!!) Bushes. Also, for Yellow Forest, you need a minimum of 9500 steps for (!!!) Bushes to appear, and that's only at a 3% chance.